# Deprecated methods in iOS

Tags: ios, deprecated

How can I check all the methods that were deprecated since iOS 4.3? Is there a website, that shows or filters all the methods that are deprecated in a give particular iOS?

Comment: you can check it in Documentation of each class.

Comment: I was thinking if i can find all the methods depricated since say ios5 or so, i can search for those methods in xcode and deal with them appropriately. I am not sure if what i intend to do makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The best place is to check in Apple Class Reference. Ex. for [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

This will be updated by them after every modification, and will be almost accurate and uptodate as compared to all other website, which in turn will get the information from here only.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(methodName)])
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: is this a website or documentation that will show all the deprecated methods? I guess **NO**

Comment: this is documentation -> https://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=deprecated+methodes

Comment: Unfortunately, some deprecated methods can do undesirable things but still actually be implemented - so they will return YES for if that object responds to them or not. You shouldn't, however, use them (as best practice - sometimes it can be necessary, unfortunately).